# Access private methods fields in another java class

Tags: java

```
public class A
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
        } 
} 

class B
{
    private static void call
        {
            int x=9;
            String name ="hello";
        } 
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to access class B private method fields in class A and print them in class A. 
Thank u..

Comment: There is no concept like a "method field". You either mean a method's local variable or you mean an instance's or class' field.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* access private fields and methods in other classes, but the whole point is that you're not supposed to. They're **private**.

So the correct thing to do is make them available to other classes by making them public. In the case of *fields* (rather than methods), you might do that with accessor methods.

**But**, if you really had to access private fields or methods, you can do it via [`java.lang.reflect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).

```
// Calling the static `call` method of `B` even though it's private:
Method m = B.class.getMethod("call");
m.setAccessible(true);
m.invoke(null);
```

But again, you shouldn't do this without a really good reason. Fix the design instead.

Answer (score 0):

*We Should Not* try to access directly the `private` members of a class in another class. This will altogether violate the rule of **Access Modifiers**. Moreover if you really want to access, you can make use of `Reflection` API provided.

Generally, in order to get the `private` class variables, you can create `public` **setters and getters** in order to access then outside that class.

Answer (score 0):

By design you cannot.  Revise the class so the method you want to call is visible to A.

That said, you can use reflection to access methods, fields etc inside B, but you cannot easily just do it with "B.call()" which most likely is what you would like to do.